# Help with differentiation.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We have $$\eta = \frac{y}{\delta (x)}$$ and 
$$\psi = u(x)\cdot \delta (x) \cdot f(\eta).$$

What is $\dfrac {\partial \psi}{\partial x}$?

Comment: seems like a long chain rule

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

You have using Product Rule:
$$
\begin{split}
\psi'(x)
 &= \frac{d}{dx}\left[ u(x) \delta(x) f\left(y \delta(x)^{-1} \right) \right] \\
 &= u'(x) \delta(x) f\left(y \delta(x)^{-1} \right)
  + u(x) \frac{d}{dx}\left[ \delta(x) f\left(y \delta(x)^{-1} \right) \right] \\
 &= u'(x) \delta(x) f\left(y \delta(x)^{-1} \right)
  + u(x) \delta'(x) f\left(y \delta(x)^{-1} \right)
  + u(x) \delta(x)  f'\left(y \delta(x)^{-1} \right)
    \frac{d}{dx} \left[ y \delta(x)^{-1} \right]
\end{split}
$$
Can you finish this using Chain Rule?